# How to transfer Ether from SC2 to SC1?

Tags: truffle

I have two contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract SC1 {
    event Log(uint gas);
    // Fallback function must be declared as external.
    function() external payable {
        // send / transfer (forwards 2300 gas to this fallback function)
        // call (forwards all of the gas)   
    }
}
```

==

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract SC2 {
    function transferToFallback(address payable _to) public payable {
        _to.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function callFallback(address payable _to) public payable {
        //(bool success,) = bank.call.value(msg.value)(payload); 
        //(bool success,) = bank.call{value: msg.value}(payload);
        //require(success, "Ether transfer failed.");
        
        (bool sent, ) = _to.call.value(msg.value)("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
   function() external payable{
    }
}
```

Problem:
I am sending Ether from SC2 to SC1 but after transfer SC1 balance is zero and SC2 balance does not change. I think the problem is with the signature of  transferToFallback function of SC2. It does not accept any argument for sending Ether. Please guide me how to send Ether from SC2   to  SC1.

My Work:
I have used truffle console for sending Ether. I am using the following command:

```
)> senderSTB.transferToFallback(receiverFB.address, {from:accounts[0]})
```

The statement executed below:

```
{ tx:
   '0x288ff695c288fe58f1a907eb95ee63c403017d73d7c202bf4d76b71a2dc4e51b',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash:
```

but there was no change in the balance of both the SC.

The migration file i.e. 2_deploy_contracts.js is:

```
const FB = artifacts.require("SC1");
const STFB = artifacts.require("SC2");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(FB);
deployer.deploy(STFB);
};
```

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `transferToFallback` transfers msg.value

```
_to.transfer(msg.value);
```

But from the console no value is sent `senderSTB.transferToFallback(receiverFB.address, {from:accounts[0]})`

If you send some amount it should reach the target contract

```
> senderSTB.transferToFallback(receiverFB.address, {from:accounts[0], value: "1000" })
```

---

The other alternative is to forward from SC2 balance

```
function transferToFallback(address payable _to, uint amount) public {
    _to.transfer(amount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you are transferring Ether from accounts[0]  to SC1, how I can transfer Ether from SC2's account to SC1's account?

Comment: @zak100 See the updated answer. You could modify `transferToFallback` to accept an amount parameter and transfer that amount from SC2 balance, or you could use `address(this).balance` if you want to transfer the full balance from SC2.